# Как сделать вывод значения ползунка в поле input

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

На основе jQ UI создал на сайте ползунок с двумя позициями(выбор диапазона цен). Подскажите как можно начальное и конечное значение вывести в поля input + что бы при изменении значений в инпуте, положение ползунков тоже изменялось

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения* **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    let minInput = $("#minimum-value"),
        maxInput = $("#maximum-value")

    const MIN_VALUE = 0
    const MAX_VALUE = 200

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min:MIN_VALUE,
      max:MAX_VALUE,
      values:[10,140],
      slide(ev,ui){
        minInput.val(ui.values[0])
        maxInput.val(ui.values[1])
      },
      create(ev,ui){
        minInput.val(10)
        maxInput.val(140)
      },
    });

    minInput.on("change",function(ev){
      if($(this).val() < MIN_VALUE){
         $(this).val(MIN_VALUE)
      }
      $( "#slider" ).slider("values",0,$(this).val())
    })
    maxInput.on("change",function(ev){
      if($(this).val() > MAX_VALUE){
         $(this).val(MAX_VALUE)
      }
      $( "#slider" ).slider("values",1,$(this).val())
    })

  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider"></div>
 Minimum: <input type="number" id="minimum-value"><br>
 Maximum: <input type="number" id="maximum-value">
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: инпута два и ползунка на слайдере тоже два минимальное значение и максимальное и они оба должны изменяться

Answer (score 0):

```html
Начальное значение:
<input id=r1 type=range value=25 oninput='n1.value = this.value' />
<input id=n1 type=number value=25 oninput='r1.value = this.value' /><br /><br />

Конечное значение:
<input id=r2 type=range value=75 oninput='n2.value = this.value'/>
<input id=n2 type=number value=75 oninput='r2.value = this.value' />
```